# Recommended hash for passwords in ASP Classic

Tags: security, asp-classic, hash

What is the slowest (therefore best) hash algorithm for passwords in ASP Classic?

EDIT: For those unaware, when hashing passwords, slower hashes are preferred to faster to help slow rainbow table style attacks.

EDIT2: And yes, of course speed isn't the only valid concern for hash selection. My question assumes that **All other things being equal**, [the slowest hash method is preferred](http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262) when hashing a password. Though collision/reverse engineering is of course a concern too, I'm prioritizing speed in this question since it is arguably the most critical factor to consider when comparing popular hash algorithms for use on passwords.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you correlate "slowest" to "best"?

Comment: You want a "strong" hashing method... but that doesn't necessarily equal "slow"

The two often go together though, so I can understand the confusion.

Comment: Something could be very slow to calculate but still have a cryptographic weakness. Slowest simply doesn't mean best. Furthermore, rainbow table style attacks are pretty much defeated using a salt.

Comment: You reverse the relation, at best it's 'best, therefore slowest', which by no means implies 'slowest, therefore best', as chills42 shows with an example

Comment: @Jon: Salts force an attacker to use a rainbow table (in place of a dictionary), they don't defeat them.

Comment: Sure, but all things being equal, slower is better. Ironically, MD5's greatest weakness for password hashing is it's too fast.

Comment: Neither does a "slow" Function. If your site is important enough, one can "just" create some specialisted hardware for it (User-Configurable FPGAs can be quite powerful and cheap), and other than that, Performance grows fast. Slow today is fast tomorrow.

Answer (score 12):

A lot of people seem to be beating on the question-asker because he's looking for a slow hash function. Actually, all other aspects being equal, a slower hash function is more secure than a fast one. This is because a slower hash function results in **slower generation of rainbow tables** and **slower brute forcing or dictionary attacks on the password**.

From Thomas Ptacek at http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262, as referenced in this [Coding Horror article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html):

> The problem is that **MD5 is fast. So
>   are its modern competitors, like SHA1
>   and SHA256**. Speed is a design goal of
>   a modern secure hash, because hashes
>   are a building block of almost every
>   cryptosystem, and usually get
>   demand-executed on a per-packet or
>   per-message basis.
>
> **Speed is exactly what you don’t want
>   in a password hash function.**
>
> Modern password schemes are attacked
>   with incremental password crackers.
>
> Incremental crackers don’t
>   precalculate all possible cracked
>   passwords. They consider each password
>   hash individually, and they feed their
>   dictionary through the password hash
>   function the same way your PHP login
>   page would. Rainbow table crackers
>   like Ophcrack use space to attack
>   passwords; incremental crackers like
>   John the Ripper, Crack, and LC5 work
>   with time: statistics and compute.
>
> The password attack game is scored in
>   time taken to crack password X. With
>   rainbow tables, that time depends on
>   how big your table needs to be and how
>   fast you can search it. With
>   incremental crackers, the time depends
>   on how fast you can make the password
>   hash function run.
>
> The better you can optimize your
>   password hash function, the faster
>   your password hash function gets, the
>   weaker your scheme is. MD5 and SHA1,
>   even conventional block ciphers like
>   DES, are designed to be fast. MD5,
>   SHA1, and DES are weak password
>   hashes. On modern CPUs, raw crypto
>   building blocks like DES and MD5 can
>   be bitsliced, vectorized, and
>   parallelized to make password searches
>   lightning fast. Game-over FPGA
>   implementations cost only hundreds of
>   dollars.

Some [comments on the PHP MD5 documentation](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.hash.php) also discuss preference for slowness.

To answer your question, it looks like BCrypt is the way to go. However, I have not been able to find any implementations for ASP Classic. If that's true, I would stick with a regular hash function like SHA512.

Comment: The important thing here is _all other aspects being equal_.  That is rarely the case.  Using speed as the primary indicator of strength is a very bad idea.

Comment: But it's not the hash function, but the hash comparison that you need to slow down -- and even, then, I would argue that you want your normal case to be fast and only slow things down when you detect an attack, say after 10 failed attempts in 15 minutes.  Then, slow it down a lot.

Comment: @tvanfosson: your point is valid unless we are assuming that the attacker has access to your raw hashes (and I think we are, as rainbow tables has been assumed as an attack). Then your application's limits won't affect anything; only the speed the hash function will slow him down.

Answer (score 5):

I'll ignore the slow part, and instead go for the "good" part.

I suggest you use SHA-512 with a salt to defeat dictionary and rainbow table attacks. I don't believe there are any known vulnerabilities for SHA-512.

Comment: Salts defeat dictionary attacks, not rainbow tables.  An attacker is forced to resort to a rainbow table attack when you add salt.

Comment: Hang on - just looked it up in wikipedia, and I was right (assuming wikipedia is) - a salt *is* used to make rainbow table attacks difficult or infeasible. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Comment: A rainbow table would still work, but you'd have to generate a new one for each salt -- which is a non-trivial process, to say the least.

Comment: Salts are here to defeat rainbow tables, not dictionary attacks, as salts are commonly known and can be added to the passwords in the dictionary easily.

Comment: @gs: But you need to add *each* salt to *each* dictionary word, making it hugely more time and space consuming.

Comment: Downvoters: please add a comment, otherwise the vote is relatively useless.

Comment: For anypody reading this years later, here's a SHA512 implementation in Classic ASP http://amadiere.com/blog/2011/02/c-net-classic-asp-password-hashing/

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to defeat brute force attacks you are better off enforcing some failed attempts window/count rather than relying on the speed of the hashing (or hash comparison) mechanism to make the attack take longer to succeed.  Lock out the account after a certain number of failed attempts within the failure window and only let new attempts be made after a significant amount of time has elapsed.

This could leave you open to a DOS attack against a well-known (administrative) account, but you could exempt certain accounts from the lockout policy or have an alternate way -- using a security question/answer -- to logon to a locked out account before the reset period has elapsed.

[EDIT] To help defeat rainbow attacks -- where the attacker has retrieved your hashed passwords and finds suitable matches that hash to the same values -- consider both using a random salt unique to each user's hashed password and a fixed salt that is part of the algorithm, not the data.  For example:

```
  testHash = computeHash( user.salt + "98hloj5674" + password );
  if (testHash == user.hashedPassword)
  {
      valid = true;
  }
```

This should invalidate the rainbow tables since, even knowing the user's salt and the hash algorithm, the values in the attacker's rainbow tables won't map onto your hashed passwords because of the addition of the fixed salt in the algorithm.

With ASP Classic, you'd have to do this in a library instead of on the page to make sure that the user couldn't see your fixed salt.

Comment: Your logic here is not consistent. You are assuming he wants to protect against rainbow attacks, which require access to the hashes. But if he does have this access, he can also run brute force attacks on the hashes. That's where the speed of the function used comes in.

Comment: He's the one who mentioned rainbow tables, I was just responding to his addition.  If he's retrieved your hashed passwords, it won't matter what algorithm or the speed since he basically has infinite time to crack the passwords -- presumably he can farm it out to all of the machines he's cracked already to do it in parallel.  The best solution is still to limit the number of failed attempts to defeat brute force attacks (which was the assumption until he edited) and add some fixed salt in addition to the stored salt when computing the hashed password to address issues of compromise.

Comment: "With ASP Classic, you'd have to do this in a library instead of on the page to make sure that the user couldn't see your fixed salt."

How would the user see the salt if it's on-page ie. within code?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim sPassword, sSalt
sPassword = "Lorem"
sSalt = "Ipsum"
With CreateObject("CAPICOM.HashedData")
  .Algorithm = 0 ' CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA1
  .Hash sPassword & sSalt
  Response.Write "Here is your hash: " & .Value
End With
```

[Capicom documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382440(VS.85).aspx)

Algorithm is any of the following:

```
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA1      = 0
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD2       = 1
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD4       = 2
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD5       = 3
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_256   = 4 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_384   = 5 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000
CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_512   = 6 - Not supported on Windows XP or 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best hash function is the one that generates no colisions and is not suspectible to rainbow-table attacks.

That means: Add a Salt (preferably a different Salt for every user), and think of using a SHA2 Hash function (or maybe RIPE-MD, I have not looked at that much):

One implementation of SHA-256 is here (i love how they call it "one-way encryption"):
http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=2565

Have not tested it though, but there are certainly SHA2 implementations for Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the [Whirlpool algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_(cryptography)) for all of my hashing needs.  It produces a 512 bit output and thus has equal space requirements to SHA-512.  Regretfully, I cannot speak authoritatively as to whether one is more secure than the other, but there do not appear to be any flagrant weaknesses in this the third version of Whirlpool.

The reference implementations are in the public domain, which is good because I rarely find this implemented by default in various tools and languages.

(If anyone knows of a good reason why SHA should be favored over Whirlpool, please let me know.)

Comment: "I rarely find [Whirlpool] implemented by default in various tools and languages."

I think you just answered your own question. Additionally, the SHA-2 family of hash functions are FIPS 180-2 approved; Whirlpool is not.

Answer (score -5):

psuedocode for the slowest method:

```
function hashPassword(password)
    sleep for 10 seconds
    return password
end function
```

This certainly isn't the most secure (or at all) but it's slow...

(I'm just pointing out that making it slower is not the answer...)

Comment: You completely miss the point...a slow hash function is slow computationally, which makes it difficult for generate rainbow tables, etc.

Comment: You can double it's efficiency by using "sleep for 20 seconds" ;-)