# ASP Password hashing algorithm

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, passwords, hash

I'm having an issue discovering what hashing algorithm is being used when inserting a password into a database, I have the password in the clear, and the hashed password itself, plus a salt, but I can't figure out what's going on in between (PHP developer, not .NET).

If anyone can help me out with what type of hashing has been used that would be ace.

- The unhashed password: a77U3b3ovil@chee
- The salt: 394279838
- The hashed password: F80ADFC2175F9DB94745E6A9B8CFA575D5B94263C523F9249620BEC958026DB4

It's being inserted into an mssql database via ASP.

Comment: If you have access to this much, don't you have access to the asp files to find the code that's doing it?

Comment: No, it's a closed system, it has taken us a long time just to get access to this much of the database, and they only plan to give us access to the database.

Comment: It might be some 1000-fold application of SHA256 composed with concatenation of the salt... how would one find out? Try some standard bcrypt routines maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Your result has 64 hex char, so 64 x 4 bits = 256 bits in total.
That means that it's either

- the result of a SHA-256 (but this is a recent algorithm that is not built in to ASP)

  use http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator to calc
- the concatenation of 2 MD5 hashes

  use http://hash.online-convert.com/md5-generator to calc

The output of SHA1, the [default hashing algorithm of ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses) has 160 bits = 40 chars, so that seems to not fit well with the data you have.

On the other hand, there might be an application salt in the code ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253673/recommended-hash-for-passwords-in-asp-classic)):

```
computeHash( user.salt + "98hloj5674" + password )
```

and if you don't know that one, there's no chance to find your answer. Can you 'guess' it? You would need a [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking) (try all the possibilities) and the point of using hashes is just that this would take you years (for SHA-256) or hours (for MD5).

I've tried the obvious options (like *sha256(Pass & Salt)* ) but none of those worked. I'm afraid there is no obvious answer without access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used

and here's a page with a few encryption methods that you could run your data through:
http://support.persits.com/encrypt/demo_text.asp