# Slowest hash function in PHP for password storage?

Tags: php, security, hash, cryptography, passwords

Which is the most slowest hash function in PHP?

Or, to put it in another way, what hash function(s) in PHP are specifically designed for password storage?

Comment: You can simply take a fast hash function and apply it again and again, until the process is slow enough for you liking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253673/recommended-hash-for-passwords-in-asp-classic

Comment: @sth: Indeed, that has the added benefit of being able to update the already computed hashes with more and more iterations and keep it slow enough over the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) is the slowest hashing algorithm currently available and is why it is most commonly recommended for hashing passwords. [Here's a PHP 5.3 implementation](https://gist.github.com/972386).

Comment: I've been seeing bcrypt once in a while for sometime now and I'm wondering why there is no native support in PHP for this seemingly best approach when it comes to password hashing? Or is bcrypt more of an idea and can be implemented in several ways?

Comment: It's an algorithm that can therefore be implemented in countless ways. Native support would be a good idea, because attackers would certainly use the fastest method available, and you are otherwise stuck in a relatively slow implementation in PHP (which won't help responsiveness or CPU usage on your servers).